# OWASP ZAP: When testing a modern web application with HTML5 drop-down menus, can AJAX Spider mouse-over to open a menu without clicking?

Tags: java, ajax

I'm attempting to test a web application where there's a top-level navigation menu.  Most of the items in it are drop-down menus where you mouse over the item, and a menu appears below the pointer, without the user having to click.  In fact, if the user does click the top-level item, the drop-down menu disappears.

Naturally, the normal Active Scan can't click out of the app's front page, and even the AJAX Spider can't find the items.  Here's how I imagine it plays out:

- Ajax Spider's mouse goes over item in navigation bar, which is a `<li>` tag containing a `<a href data-toggle="dropdown">` tag.
- menu becomes visible a `<ul>` tag right after the `<a>` tag, and the inspector shows `::after` after that tag
- Ajax Spider clicks menu item to see if it triggers an HTTP request
- menu becomes invisible; `::after` disappears.  A `class="open"` attribute appears on the outer `<li>` tag but it has no effect.
- Ajax looks for new links and doesn't find any

so... I think what I need to do is to tell it to hover on `<a data-toggle="dropdown">` links and then look for `<a role="menuitem">` tags to click nearby.  Is there any feature that can do anything like that?

thanks.  in the meantime I suppose I can use the browser to click through all the menu items; that seems to make scans aware of it.  but I'd rather the process didn't depend on my thoroughness as a clicker of functions.